# ESXI Snapshots on a CentOS VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos6, snapshot

On reverting back to a snapshot on one of my CentOS VM's the date is obviously set back to the original snapshot date.  I was wondering if anyone knew of any other changes to the server (apart from the date) that would need to be changed that "could" cause system issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your VM will revert all changes to disk (not just the date) made since the snapshot was taken.  Essentially a revert is telling the VM to discard all changes made to the disk since the snapshot was taken. The longer the snapshot has been in place the bigger the impact you will see to the system state of the VM.

Anything that stores information on the VMDKs associated with the VM will be reverted back to the state they were in when the snapshot was taken.  You are seeing the date/time change because that information is stored on disk :)

Comment: Technically it is stored in which-ever virtualized hardware timekeeping device is being [emulated](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf). That information is saved to the hosts disk, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on Linux Boxes without "VMWare Tools" installed (also when getting back from "paused" state). After installing tools and check that "Synchronize time with host" option is on I get rid of this problem.

One more tip - I've found that if You want to be 100% sure about system consistency You should power off VM, take snapshot and than power it on (especially on VMs with DBs).

Comment: There remains a (recommendation)[http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427] to use NTP over VMware Tools synchronization.

Comment: "Note : VMware recommends you to use NTP instead of VMware Tools periodic time synchronization. NTP is an industry standard and ensures accurate timekeeping in your guest."